# Strike-through in HTML Emails

Tags: html, email

I'm currently coding an HTML email, using MailChimp to test it, and eventually to send it.

The email advertises several sales, which are displayed using the HTML `strike` tag. For some reason, these `strike` tags are not coming through to the finished test emails.

Code as it appears in MailChimp:

```
<strike>$12.95</strike> SALE! $9.95
```

Code in the test email, retrieved using Chrome Web Tools:

```
$12.95 SALE! $9.95
```

I've personally verified that this is happening in Gmail, Outlook 2007, and Yahoo! Mail. A quick perusal of my MailChimp Inbox Inspector results tells me the problem is definitely not limited to these three.

Any idea why this might be happening? Is there a more reliable alternative I could use without resorting to images?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An in-line style of `text-decoration:line-through` is your best option and it seems to be [widely supported](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). The PDF on that page has a much larger result set for many more clients.

Comment: +1. I stumbled upon this problem, and I think we should avoid using <strike</strike> tag as the guys at [MDN suggested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike).

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
<span style='text-decoration: line-through;'>12.95</span> SALE $9.95
```

Answer (score 4):

These are the styles to color the text and srikethrough the text:

```
<span style="color:red; text-decoration:line-through;">
    <span style="color:black;">black with red strikethrough</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try the css property `text-decoration: line-through;` - might be more widely accepted...

Answer (score 2):

At risk of having your style stripped from the email, you can try an inline style on each element.

```
<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">$12.95</span>
```

But the thing to really remember in this case is that html newsletters are finicky and cannot be reliably styled to be identical in all of the mail clients. That's pretty much why it is suggested to rely entirely on old style tabled html with no background images or modern css.
While you CAN add styles and you might get them to avoid being stripped out, it is still not guaranteed in every client.

My suggestion is to go all raw tabled html and resort to images if it;s that important. Otherwise compose a list of the mail clients that mean the most to you and get it working however you can for all of those and just forget about the rest.

Comment: Very useful. Outlook.com supports html editing out of the box, for Gmail, one has to create the html elsewhere (e. g. on website) and then copy/paste into mail, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3561/24599 .